Login with Microsoft External Account -Issue when the user cancels the consent prompt during authentication
I'm using Microsoft external authentication in a .NET 5 Razor Pages application, and I'm encountering an issue when the user cancels the consent prompt during authentication. The behavior works as expected for personal Microsoft accounts — when a user cancels, they are redirected back to the login page successfully. However, when a work account user cancels, I receive the following exception:

Local host Error link


An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
Exception: consent_required;Description=AADSTS65004: User declined to consent to access the app. Trace ID: 88696573-49b5-472b-8db9-40bd03711600 Correlation ID: 9babdc71-9c05-4910-8f29-c5b3aa6b5cc1 Timestamp: 2024-10-14 06:05:38Z;Uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=65004
Unknown location


Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.**
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()**


The relevant part of my code for configuring Microsoft authentication looks like this:

public static class MicrosoftAuthExtension
{
    public static void AddMicrosoftAuth(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
            {
                IConfigurationSection microsoftAuthNSection = configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Microsoft");
                options.ClientId = microsoftAuthNSection["ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = microsoftAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/Identity/Account/MicrosoftExternalAccountCallBack");
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Identity/Account/Login");
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });
    }
}


Everything works perfectly when user accept consent.

enter image description here
I’ve set options.AccessDeniedPath to redirect back to the login page if consent is denied.
This works fine for personal accounts, but throws an exception for work accounts.
Does anyone know why this might be happening only for work accounts, and how I can handle this gracefully for both personal and work accounts? Any help would be appreciated!

Can you share the GitHub repo?

@DasariKamali - Sorry i can't.

Hi Prakash Rajput, try to use OnRemoteFailure, here is the sample code for you.

@JasonPan it is working perfectly, Thank you!

@PrakashRajput Please allow me summarize it as answer below, have a nice day.

We can Invoke OnRemoteFailure when there is a remote failure.
Here is the sample code
services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
{
   IConfigurationSection microsoftAuthNSection = configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Microsoft");
   options.ClientId = microsoftAuthNSection["ClientId"];
   options.ClientSecret = microsoftAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
   options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/Identity/Account/MicrosoftExternalAccountCallBack");
   options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Identity/Account/Login");
   options.SaveTokens = true;

   options.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthEvents
   {
       OnRemoteFailure = context =>
       {
           if (context.Request.Query["error"] == "consent_required")
           {
               context.Response.Redirect("/Identity/Account/Login?error=consent_declined");
               context.HandleResponse(); 
               return Task.CompletedTask;
           }

           context.Response.Redirect("/Identity/Account/Login?error=unexpected_error");
           context.HandleResponse();
           return Task.CompletedTask;
       }
   };
});

